# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like this has to do with the AJAX call. Not really sure what is going on. The error is technically being thrown within the jQuery file at line 584 which defines the `isArraylike(obj)` function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var width_of_grams = $(window).width();
  var new_pic_height = (width_of_grams /7);
  $("img.gram_photo").css('height', (width_of_grams) / 7);
  $("#instafeed").css('height', 2*new_pic_height);

  $(window).resize(function() {  
    var width_of_grams = $(window).width();
    var new_pic_height = (width_of_grams /7);
    $("img.gram_photo").css('height', (width_of_grams) / 7);
    $("#instafeed").css('height', 2*new_pic_height);
  });


  $("#school_application_fls_center_name").change(function(){
    var center_name = document.getElementById("school_application_fls_center_name").value;
    var formdata = {center: center_name}; 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/application/get_programs_for_center",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        success: function(response){
          var options = $("#school_application_program_name"); 
          console.log(response);
          $.each(response, function(i,item) {
            options.append($("<option />").val(response[i].id).text(response[i].name)); 
          });
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the jQuery library code that throws the error:

```
function isArraylike( obj ) {
  var length = obj.length,
    type = jQuery.type( obj );

    if ( type === "function" || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    } 

    if ( obj.nodeType === 1 && length ) {
        return true;
    }

    return type === "array" || length === 0 ||
        typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj; //THIS LINE THROWS ERROR
}
```

N.B. When I remove all of the callback function in the success part of the AJAX request,
   and just put a `console.log` to confirm I am making it to the callback successfully it prints
    my log message and does not throw the error.

Comment: Which HTMLElement object has the `selected` property? What does `.getElementById("school_application_fls_center_name")` return? A `HTMLSelectElement` object?

Comment: `<select id=​"school_application_fls_center_name" name=​"school_application[fls_center_name]​">​…​</select>​`

Comment: @undefined it should be `.value` not `.selected`

Comment: That object doesn't have `selected`property, it has `selectedIndex` and `selectedOptions` properties. If you want to get the value, read the `value` property.

Comment: thank you I changed it to `value` and I get the same error.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Is that all of your code?

Comment: `gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0'`

Comment: Yes that is all of the jQuery that I wrote for this project.

Answer (score 8):

I think your response is a JSON string. Try passing

```
dataType: 'json'
```

in your ajax parameters, or explicitly deserialise it with:

```
response = JSON.parse(response)
```

before you call $.each.

Browser session:

```
// Create some JSON:
json = '["foo", "bar"]'
"["foo", "bar"]"

// Try parsing it, to check it is indeed JSON:
JSON.parse(json)
["foo", "bar"]

// But without parsing it, call $.each on it - we get your error:
$.each(json, function(idx, thing) {console.log(thing)})
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '13' in ["foo", "bar"]

// Now try $.each and JSON.parse - success!
$.each(JSON.parse(json), function(idx, thing) {console.log(thing)})
foo VM410:2
bar VM410:2
["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I just worked after passing dataType: 'json'. Upvoted for this

Answer (score 0):

So when I was getting this error, I was not actually correctly supplying the response on the server side. In my Rails Controller I had:

```
def controller_method_to_handle_post
  render nothing :true
end
```

So I basically had a null response coming from the server. So then when I went to parse
the response with `$.each`I hit the jQuery error which is saying it can't iterate through this null object that I am passing it.

Comment: I suspect you still need to do some JSON deserialising in your JavaScript. If you do, then the string "null" will be converted to a null object, then when you try $.each on the null result you will get a slightly more helpful error, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"